# Hyperbolic numbers and their polar form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How can I implement [Hyperbolic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) in *Mathematica*? How could I express their polar form? How could I calculate their power?

Comment: [How to write a good question!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do with them. For the "standard" case x+j*y with j^2=1, could use symmetric 2x2 matrices.

Answer (score 6):

```
ScalarQ[c_] := NumericQ[c] && ! MatchQ[Head[c], Complex | Hyperbolic];

Hyperbolic /: Hyperbolic[a_, 0] := a;

Hyperbolic /: c_?ScalarQ + Hyperbolic[a_, b_] := Hyperbolic[c + a, b];

Hyperbolic /: Hyperbolic[a_, b_] + Hyperbolic[c_, d_] := 
 Hyperbolic[a + c, b + d];

Hyperbolic /: c_?ScalarQ*Hyperbolic[a_, b_] /; ScalarQ[c] := 
 Hyperbolic[c a, c b];

Hyperbolic /: Hyperbolic[a_, b_]*Hyperbolic[c_, d_] := 
 Hyperbolic[a c + b*d, b c + a d];

Hyperbolic /: Power[Hyperbolic[a_, b_], 0] := 1;

Hyperbolic /: Power[Hyperbolic[a_, b_], -1] := 
 Hyperbolic[a/(a^2 - b^2), -b/(a^2 - b^2)];

Hyperbolic /: Power[Hyperbolic[a_, b_], n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Hyperbolic[a, b] Power[Hyperbolic[a, b], n - 1];

Hyperbolic /: Power[Hyperbolic[a_, b_], n_Integer?Negative] := 
 1/Power[Hyperbolic[a, b], -n];

Hyperbolic /: Power[Hyperbolic[a_, b_], x_?ScalarQ] := 
 Which[a^2 - b^2 > 1, 
  Hyperbolic[(Sqrt[Abs[a^2 - b^2]])^x*
    Cosh[x*ArcTan[b/a]], (Sqrt[Abs[a^2 - b^2]])^x*
    Sinh[x*ArcTan[b/a]]], a^2 - b^2 < -1, 
  Hyperbolic[(Sqrt[Abs[a^2 - b^2]])^x*
    Sinh[x*ArcTan[b/a]], (Sqrt[Abs[a^2 - b^2]])^x*
    Cosh[x*ArcTan[b/a]]], a^2 - b^2 == 0, 0];

Hyperbolic /: 
 f_[Hyperbolic[a_, b_]] /; MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] := 
 Hyperbolic[f[a], b f'[a]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of the notebook:

```
$Post = #/.J->{-1,1}/.{x_,y_}->(x+y)/2+J(y-x)/2&;
```

Use like this:

```
In:= Log[J]

Out:= (I Pi)/2 - (I Pi J)/2

In:= (3J+5)^3

Out:= 260 + 252 J

In:= I^J

Out:= I J
```